# Separating XNA and Content into different solutions

Tags: visual-studio, xna

Is it possible to separate the XNA content pipeline project into a different solution using visual studio? I have specific reasons for keeping the content project separate from the main game project.

Comment: While a default content project is created and linked to your XNA project, it is possible to link other content projects. Have you tried creating a content project in another solution and attempting to link it?

Comment: I think the problem is that I do not know how to link it. Sorry I was not more clear.

Comment: I think it is possible, though not through Visual Studio. You need to add the following to your .csproj file for your XNA project:

<ProjectReference Include="..\PATH\TO\MY\CONTENTPROJ.contentproj">
      <Name>OtherProj_Win32Content</Name>
      <XnaReferenceType>Content</XnaReferenceType>
    </ProjectReference>

Comment: If you create that as an answer I will mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible, though not through Visual Studio. You need to add the following to your .csproj file for your XNA project:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\PATH\TO\MY\CONTENTPROJ.contentproj">    
    <Name>OtherProj_Win32Content</Name> 
    <XnaReferenceType>Content</XnaReferenceType> 
</ProjectReference>
```